# NIFI: join two tables from different databases

Tags: apache-nifi

I have two transactional tables originating from different databases in different servers. I would like to join them based on common attribute and store the result altogether in different database.

I have been looking for various options in NIFI to execute this as a job which runs monthly.

So far, I have been trying out various options but doesn't seem to work out. For example, I used ExecuteSQL1 & ExecuteSQL2 -> MergeContent-> PutSQL

Could anyone provide pointers on the same?

Comment: just an idea: run both sql and split records, extract desired attribute for all records, wait somehow until all records prepared, sort queue by the desired attribute, then try mergecontent or write custom script to merge

Answer (score 1):

NiFi is not really meant to do a streaming join like this. The best option would be to implement the join in the SQL query using a single ExecuteSQL processor.

Comment: Can't do multiple DBs with ExecuteSQL though

Answer (score 0):

As Bryan said, NiFi doesn't (currently) do this. Perhaps look at [Presto](https://prestodb.github.io/), you can set up multiple connections "under the hood" and use its JDBC driver to do what Bryan described, a join across tables in different DBs.

I'm thinking about adding a JoinTables processor that would let you join two tables using two different DBCPConnectionPool controller services, but there are lots of things to consider, such as being able to do the join in memory for example. For joining dimensions to fact tables, we could try to load the smaller table into memory and then we could do more of a streaming join for larger fact tables, for example. Feel free to file a New Feature Jira if you like, and we can discuss there.

Comment: Is the "JoinTables" processor available in the latest release or any JIRA request open for the same? I am looking for a similar processor. Thanks

Comment: No I haven't written it up yet, I want to characterize the use case(s) better, such as a "streaming join" vs an in-memory record join.